# Doctrine ORM Custom ORM\JoinColumn Query in Symfony 6/7

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, api-platform.com

I want to load the last chat_message created by an contact loaded into the chat_partner. Due to this i added an private $lastMessage property, which i thought should can load it over an OneToOne Association into the Chat_Partner. But im failing on creating an nested ORM query with an OR condition on the JoinColumn parameters :o

The entities are the following:

Chat Message:

| id | sender | receiver | message |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15 | 37 | Hi, how are you ? |
| 2 | 37 | 15 | Im fine, thanks! |

Chat Partner:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\OrderFilter;
use ApiPlatform\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\SearchFilter;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiFilter;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata as Metadata;
use App\Repository\ChatMessageRepository;
use App\Repository\ChatPartnerRepository;
use App\State\ChatPartnerStateProvider;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Sequence;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Attribute\Groups;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ChatPartnerRepository::class)]
#[ApiResource(
    operations: [
        new Metadata\GetCollection(security: 'is_granted("ROLE_CHAT_PARTNER_GETCOLLECTION")', provider: ChatPartnerStateProvider::class),
        new Metadata\Post(securityPostDenormalize: 'is_granted("CREATE", object)'),
    ],
    normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['chatpartner:read']],
    denormalizationContext: ['groups' => ['chatpartner:write']],
    mercure: true
)]

#[ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties: ['partner.shop' => 'exact'])]

class ChatPartner
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'chatPartnersFrom')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    #[Groups(['chatpartner:read', 'chatpartner:write'])]
    private ?Contact $contact = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'chatPartnersTo')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    #[Groups(['chatpartner:read', 'chatpartner:write'])]
    private ?Contact $partner = null;

    #[Groups(['chatpartner:read'])]
    #[ApiFilter(OrderFilter::class, properties: ['lastMessage.createdAt'])]
    #[ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity: ChatMessage::class)]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(name: 'partner_id', referencedColumnName: 'receiver_id')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(name: 'contact_id', referencedColumnName: 'sender_id')]
    #[ORM\OrderBy(['lastMessage.createdAt' => 'ASC'])]

    private ?ChatMessage $lastMessage = null;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getContact(): ?Contact
    {
        return $this->contact;
    }

    public function setContact(?Contact $contact): static
    {
        $this->contact = $contact;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPartner(): ?Contact
    {
        return $this->partner;
    }

    public function setPartner(?Contact $partner): static
    {
        $this->partner = $partner;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLastMessage(): ?ChatMessage
    {
      return $this->lastMessage;
    }
}
```

I tried adding an OneToOne Association which is at the first moment working ok, but only one one side. To correct fetch the lastmessage he has to check both sides, so that this query should be executed via the attrbiutes:

```
    private function searchForLastMessage(ChatPartner $chatPartner)
    {
        return $this->chatMessageRepository->createQueryBuilder('cm')
        ->andWhere('(cm.receiver = :contact AND cm.sender = :partner) OR (cm.receiver = :partner AND cm.sender = :contact)')
        ->setParameters([
            'contact' => $chatPartner->getContact(),
            'partner' => $chatPartner->getPartner(),
        ])
        ->orderBy('cm.createdAt', 'DESC')
        ->setMaxResults(1)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getOneOrNullResult();
    }
```

I tried a lot but i dont find a way to ensure that over the ORM attributes. I need that because i want to also sort by the creation in my Api Platform API and receive updates via mercure.

Anyone has a hint how i could solve this ?